# Python html parsing

Tags: python, html, parsing

I need to parse html emails that will be similar but not exactly the same. I will be looking for things like dates, amounts, vendors, ect., but depending on who the email came from, the markup will be different.

How could I parse out those common things from lots of different html markup in python?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Just *don't* use regular expressions :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You absolutely need to consider [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library.

Comment: Looks like a good way to parse the html. Will BeatifulSoup also cleanup/fix mal formed html?

Comment: @user634529. The answer is YES.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse HTML in Python.

Comment: @downvoter: Are you trying to get a badge for downvoting everything or something? The link's not dead and you didn't leave a comment. I'm assuming the same person downvoted all 3 answers here.

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoup or lxml are decent HTML parsers. BeautifulSoup is a bit more handy but has some odds and ends.