# How to parse a html file and get the text which is in between the tags by using Python?

Tags: python, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing HTML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717541/parsing-html-in-python)

I have searched more over on the internet for get the text which is in between the tags by using Python. Can you guys please explain?

Comment: Uhm, http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html ?

Comment: Or http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html or http://lxml.de/

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870446/whats-the-most-forgiving-html-parser-in-python or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120129/python-html-parsing or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895102/python-html-parsing or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505041/best-library-to-parse-html-with-python-3-and-example

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse HTML:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<html><body>
                        <div id="a" class="c1">
                            We want to get this
                        </div>
                        <div id="b">
                            We don't want to get this
                        </div></body></html>""")
print soup('div', id='a').text
```

This outputs

```
We want to get this
```

Answer (score -1):

The htmlparser provided in the link in the comments above is probably the more robust way to go. But if you have a simple bit of content that is between particular tags you can use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html)

```
import re
html = '<html><body><div id='blah-content'>Blah</div><div id='content-i-want'>good stuff</div></body></html>'
m = re.match(r'.*<div.*id=\'content-i-want\'.*>(.*?)</div>', html)
if m:
    print m.group(1) # Should print 'good stuff'
```

Comment: I disagree with using regular expressions to parse HTML. Your code only works in the simplest possible example. If the div had any other attributes (like a class) it would fail. If the text in the div had a `>`, it would fail. For anything but an unrealistically simple example, regex is not sufficient. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Yes a HTML parser library is the way to go. But there might be a situation where you are reading from a fixed HTML format or you don't have anything but built-in python libraries. In which case the code above, which I have corrected should work. Yes it is not as robust as a HTML parser, hence the first line of my answer.