# Extract text/data from html source code

Tags: html

I am attempting to extract a piece of text that is nested between the html code `<span class="code">` and `</span>`.  The idea, is that I need the information stored between those.

How can extract just that information from a webpage automatically?

Comment: What language are you parsing it with? Javascript? Ruby? Please be more specific.

Comment: almost every language offers this feature

Comment: For instance, [using Python and BeautifulSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080506/how-to-parse-a-html-file-and-get-the-text-which-is-in-between-the-tags-by-using) you would have: `print soup('span', class='code').text`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're doing it in Ruby or Javascript, because you didn't specify and those are the languages I know how to do it in best.

In Ruby, you'd first install the [Nokogiri gem](http://nokogiri.org/) via

```
gem install nokogiri
```

And your code would look something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://your-url.example.com/foo/bar))
value = doc.css('span.code');

p value
```

---

For Javascript, you can use jQuery (not really sure how to do it without).

```
var value = $('span.code').value;
```